# Creating a new array from JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am new to JSON and Javascript. I have JSON object as below:

```
const text = {"recordset": [
    {
        "planned_date": "2020-06-29T00:00:00.000Z",
        "quantity": 9,
    },
    {
        "planned_date": "2020-07-06T00:00:00.000Z",
        "quantity": 12,
    },
    {
        "planned_date": "2020-07-13T00:00:00.000Z",
        "quantity": 13,
    },
    {
        "planned_date": "2020-07-20T00:00:00.000Z",
        "quantity": 9,
    }
 
]};
```

I tried to create a new array which only take the "quantity" as such but failed miserably:

```
for (i in text.recordset) {
    for (j in text.recordset[i].quantity) {
        newText += text.recordset[i].quantity[j]
    }
}
```

What I want is new array as below:

```
const newText = [9, 12, 13, 9]
```

Comment: You don't have a JSON object, that's an object literal. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2904131

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of .map method in js array.

```js
const text = {"recordset": [
    {
        "planned_date": "2020-06-29T00:00:00.000Z",
        "quantity": 9,
    },
    {
        "planned_date": "2020-07-06T00:00:00.000Z",
        "quantity": 12,
    },
    {
        "planned_date": "2020-07-13T00:00:00.000Z",
        "quantity": 13,
    },
    {
        "planned_date": "2020-07-20T00:00:00.000Z",
        "quantity": 9,
    }
 
]};

var result = text.recordset.map(obj => obj.quantity);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

text.recordset.map(r => r.quantity)